# What is the first pasuk in the Torah that begins within the letter tes?

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, chumash

I am wondering if someone knows the first pasuk in the Torah that begins within the letter Tes?  Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is any *passuk* in Chumash that begins with the letter *tes*.

Comment: What about ח? Or י?

Comment: A quick search on Sefaria shows nothing starting with tet: https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%98&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance

Answer (score 3):

According to [Torat Emet](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00720_part_9.html), the first one is in [Beresheet 19:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.19.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> "טֶרֶם יִשְׁכָּבוּ וְאַנְשֵׁי הָעִיר אַנְשֵׁי סְדֹם נָסַבּוּ עַל הַבַּיִת מִנַּעַר וְעַד זָקֵן כָּל הָעָם מִקָּצֶה"

Comment: The other 3 places in the Torah are Gen 31:39 Num 32:26 and Deu 29:10. In Neviim there are three total Micah 7:4, Nahum 1:7 and Hab 1:13